# Pdf File In asset folder not open in thirdparty app

Tags: android, android-assets

Hi I am new in android  i have some PDF file that exist in this path `asset/pdf/example.pdf`

when i try PDF file  with this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    File file = new File("file:///android_asset/pdf/example.pdf");
    intent.setDataAndType( Uri.fromFile( file ), "application/pdf" );
    startActivity(intent);
```

i get  this error & know it's because third party has no access to file
what is solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> know it's because third party has no access to file

`file:///android_asset/` only works for `WebView` AFAIK.

> what is solution?

You can use [my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider), which offers a `ContentProvider` that can serve a file from `assets/`.

Or, you can implement your own `ContentProvider` that can serve the file from `assets/`.

Or, you can copy the asset to a local file (e.g., in `getFilesDir()` or `getCacheDir()`), [then use `FileProvider` to serve that local file](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider).

Comment: dude i read your GITHUB  project too before ask question but cannot handle it again ! i new and don't knew how to use stream provider can you wrote base on my file path and give me example ?

Comment: @MohamadAmin: [The `StreamProvider` `demo/` project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider/tree/master/demo) demonstrates serving a file from assets, among other things. So do many of my book's drag-and-drop samples, such as [this one](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/DragDrop/Legacy) (the `StreamProvider` is used in the `drag/` app module).

Comment: i cannot handle it :( trying for two hours